# Problem with materials on bevelled edges in Eevee

Tags: bevel

Can anyone help me work out why bevelled edges don't have a smooth texture in Eevee (at least in my current case)? I eventually want to create game assets, so ideally I want my models to look good in Eevee.

My model renders as intended in cycles, but in Eevee the bevelled edges don't show up as smooth. Here is how the edges render in Eevee:

[image]

Is it a problem with the texture I created or my geometry? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a bevel node or a bevel modifier or did you manually edited your mesh to create bevels on those edges?

Comment: I just selected the edges and used the bevel tool (CTRL + B).

Comment: Can anyone help?